# How to properly simplify with variable constraints (including infinity)

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm new to mathematica and have trouble simplifying an expression.

I want to simplify the expression:

```
Exp[-s*t]
```

under the constraint that t=+Inf and s is a positive real number.
I try it using:

```
Simplify[Exp[-s*t], {t = +Infinity, Element[s, PositiveReals]}]
```

However, it will get simplified to

```
E^(s (-\[Infinity]))
```

instead of the desired

```
0
```

Why is this ?

(btw.: I'm using Mathematica 9)

Comment: try ` Simplify[-x*(Exp[-2*s*t] - 1) == x /. t -> Infinity,Element[s, PositiveReals]]`?

Comment: still "x - E^(s (-\[Infinity])) x == x". Please note, that I simplified the expression in the question to make the problem more obvious.

Comment: Either `Assuming[s > 0, x - E^(s (-\[Infinity])) x == x // Simplify]` or `Simplify[x - E^(s (-\[Infinity])) x == x, s > 0]` evaluate to `True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Simplify[Exp[-s*t] /. t -> \[Infinity], s > 0]

(*  0  *)
```

Have fun!